# Android: Detect headphones as well as headset?

Tags: android, audio

I've got my code working using the `isWiredHeadsetOn()` method in AudioManager as long as I use the headset that came with my phone. If I use a pair of headphones without an inbuilt microphone, `isWiredHeadsetOn()` returns false, which I suppose is fair enough, but isn't what I want! Is there a way to detect both headsets and headphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a broadcast receiver for ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG. Then you get events when the headset is connected or disconnected.

I think it should work for bluetooth devices but am not 100% sure to be honest.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid doing that just in case there's a time where the event isn't fired in addition to maintaining a state in my app. oh well, this is probably the only way to do it.

Comment: have your reciever recieve intent  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> this requires  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG fires before BOOT_COMPLETED, at least on my phone.