# Is there a way to detect headphones natively?

Tags: android, native, detect, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Detect headphones as well as headset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606297/android-detect-headphones-as-well-as-headset)

There's an easy way over java, but, since we're doing a library we want to skip the jni part.

Comment: Please rephrase.  You don't want to do Java, and you're creating a library, but you don't want to use the JNI?  Huh?

Comment: I guess by "natively" the author ment "from the C++/NDK level".

Comment: Odd how that happens.  Re-read the question, and now it makes perfect sense!  Doh...

Comment: yup, they actually closed my question, and it's not the same :(
first time here (so actually dunno what to do next) this is, I want to know if there's a way by doing this entirely on C++ side, nothing to do with java side.